# "Permission denied" error when editing /etc/ld.so.conf

Tags: files, sudo, permissions

When I run this command it fails:

```
sudo echo '/usr/local/lib' >> /etc/ld.so.conf 
bash: /etc/ld.so.conf: Permission denied
```

I don't have any problem running `sudo` for other tasks. I am using Ubuntu 12.04. It works when connected as `root`.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: You do a sudo echo but the remainder of that command is NOT executed as sudo (the rerouting is not done as sudo ;-) )

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From memory this should do it:

```
sudo sh -c "echo '/usr/local/lib' >> /etc/ld.so.conf"
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation on why this works?

Comment: @Bar I think it works because `sudo` only applies to one command at a time. The quotes group two commands (an `echo` followed by an `>>`) into one. An alternate approach is to open an editor with `sudo` and do the edits manually, i.e. `sudo gedit /usr/local/lib`.